# How can we determine the coordinates of the points?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

We have the following figure:

[image]

The following points are given:

$$N= (8.98,99.82,54.25); M= (31.16,97.78,54.25); \\  
L= (74.65,70.61,54.25); K= (84.85,51.91,54.25); \\ 
J= (9.07,95.48,119.35); I= (30.77,93.44,119.35); \\ 
H= (70.96,68.36,119.35); G= (81.81,50,119.35)  $$

and also the following planes are given:

$$E(ABN): -9446,05x + 911,57y+ 48,17z = 8781,16; \\ 
E(NMS): 110,67x +1203,27y-193,13z=110626,19; \\ 
E(HQP):3026,52x - 4952,5y + 0,21z=-123765,61; \\ 
E(DCI):X= (25.77 / 40.74 / 182.28) +r  (3.05 / 31/ 0) +s(5 /52,7 / -62.93) \\ 
E(KLP):X=(84.85 / 51.91 / 54.25) +t (-10.2 / 18.7 / 0) +p (-17.58 / 14.19 / -54.25) \\ 
E(FOA):X= (63.36 / 38.71 / 182.28) +v(14.76 / 9.03 / -128.28) + w (-63.36 / -38.71 / 0) \\ 
E(GHL):X= (81.81 / 50 / 119.35) +d (-10.85 / 18.36 / 0) +c (-7.16 / 20.61 / -65.1) \\ 
E(IJN):X= (30.77 / 93.82 / 119.35) +m (-21.7 / 2.04 / 0) +t(-21.79 / 6.38 / -65.1) $$

How can we determine the coordinates of the other points?

Comment: What does this mean? $$\color{red}{X=(25.77/40.74/182.28)+r(3.05/31/0)+s(5/52,7/−62.93)}$$

Comment: I mean $X=(25.77, \ 40.74, \ 182.28)+r(3.05, \ 31, \ 0)+s(5, \ 52.7, \ −62.93)$, i.e. these e are vectors. @caverac

Comment: Do you have an idea? @caverac

Answer (score 1):

You can put a cutting plane through the figure parallel to $ABC$ near the top or parallel to $QRS$ near the bottom, truncate the figure at the cutting plane, and relabel the points so that you have a new figure that looks "just like" the old one (except for small changes to the locations of some points) and satisfies all the given equations.

So I think the answer is that you cannot determine the coordinates of the other points.

Comment: Ah so, we cannot determine the coordinates as intersections points of planes, can we?

Comment: Could you explain to me further why we cannot determine the coordinates of the other points?

Comment: Consider the point $S,$ for example. This point would be determined by the three planes $ABN,$ $NMS,$ and $QRS,$ but you have equations for only two of those planes, and you have no other information that would pinpoint the location of $S.$ (Based on the diagram, you can say it is somewhere between $N$ and the intersection of the plane $NMS$ with the line $AT,$ but that's a lot of possible points.)